# Modal Dialog does not show on button click, but area grays out ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, partial-views, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have a button using which I want to render a modal dialog. The button is:

```
<button id="runButton" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Run</button>
<div class="modal fade" id="RunModal" role="dialog" data-url='@Url.Action("_Run", "Tests")'></div>
```

My javascript function is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#runButton').click(function () {
            var url = $('#RunModal').data('url');
            $.get(url, function (data) {
                $("#RunModal").html(data);
                $("#RunModal").modal('show');
            });
        });
    });
```

The modal dialog's partial view is:

```
<div id="RunModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="RunModal" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h6 class="modal-title">Run</h6>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form>
                    <fieldset>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Value Set Name</label>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter the value set name" class="form-control small-input" id="newValueSet" />
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <div class="btn-group">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Run</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my controller function is:

```
public ActionResult _Run()
{
    return PartialView();
}
```

When I click the button, it goes to the controller and returns the view but the modal dialog does not show, and the web page area is grayed out. Any pointers towards what could cause this type of behavior would be of great help. The Inspector does not throw any error on the console when debugged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly,I find the id `RunModal`is repeated in your view and parital view.And then you should both show the `dalog` in view and partial view.

Here is a demo worked(I changed the id(`RunModal`) in view to `RunModal1`):
Controller:

```
        public IActionResult Index()
        {

            return View();
        }
        public ActionResult _Run()
        {
            return PartialView("~/Views/Tests/_Run.cshtml");
        }
```

View:

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<h1>Index</h1>

<button id="runButton" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Run</button>
<div class="modal fade" id="RunModal1" role="dialog" data-url='@Url.Action("_Run", "Tests")'></div>


@section scripts{ 
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
       
    });
    $('#runButton').click(function () {
        var url = $('#RunModal1').data('url');
        
        $.get(url, function (data) {
            $("#RunModal1").html(data);
            $("#RunModal").modal('show');
            $("#RunModal1").modal('show');
          
        });
    });
</script>
}
```

Result:

[image]